# How to build FCM-like services for remote notification when app is killed?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, build, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there a framework, web service with library or a guide to how to build a service like Firebase for remote push notifications for iOS and Android when apps are killed?

I mean, is there any known way to build something as -Firebase?

Answer (score 0):

iOS  when apps are killed will call
     `- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application` this function. so you can request in it

Comment: It's the same thing, just placed in another class, but just before app is killed. So it didn't change anything and my observer still don't work.